# Dynamically update app build version for both ios and android - React Native

Tags: react-native, version

Right now I am updating build version from xcode and android studio respectively, also I want to show app version inside the app as well. Is there any way, so that I update version at a single point inside project, and both ios and android versions get updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can dynamically update this using this library [react-native-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-version)

Comment: I looked into this library, is there any way with it that I can get the current version number in react native code and show it inside the app?